# ANT Script to deploy a War file in MobileFirst Server to create run time

Tags: ant, war, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am using Ant script to deploy a war file in mobile first server to create run time. But I am not sure about the ANT Script, I am getting errors regarding database configuration.

This is the error I am getting by running Ant Script:

```
     Building project
        command: 'C:\Program Files\agent\opt\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin\ant.bat' -f 'C:\Program Files\agent\var\work\MF-Component\wardeploy.xml'
        Buildfile: C:\Program Files\agent\var\work\MF-Component\wardeploy.xml

        install:
        [configureapplicationserver] Logging output of task <configureApplicationServer> to file C:\Users\miracle\Documents\IBM MobileFirst Platform Server Data\Configuration Logs\configureApplicationServer_2016_02_12_03_35_41.log
        [configureapplicationserver] WARNING: The Reports database is deprecated in IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation since V7.0.0.
        [configureapplicationserver] Use Operational Analytics instead.
        [configureapplicationserver] See http://ibm.biz/knowctr#SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_op_analytics_overview.html

        BUILD FAILED
        C:\Program Files\agent\var\work\MF-Component\wardeploy.xml:33: Element <db2> inside <database kind="Worklight"> inside <configureApplicationServer>: Database does not contain the expected tables. The test table GADGET_USER_PREF was not found. 
    You may create the required tables through an invocation of <configureDatabase>.

    Total time: 4 seconds
    Caught: com.urbancode.air.ExitCodeException: Command failed with exit code: 1
    com.urbancode.air.ExitCodeException: Command failed with exit code: 1
        at com.urbancode.air.CommandHelper.runCommand(CommandHelper.groovy:195)
        at com.urbancode.air.CommandHelper$runCommand$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at com.urbancode.air.CommandHelper.runCommand(CommandHelper.groovy:121)
        at com.urbancode.air.CommandHelper$runCommand.call(Unknown Source)
        at ant.run(ant.groovy:123)
```

Here I don't need any tables to deploy the war file but it was asking for table. For deploying the war file it needs to have database. That I have given the credentials but it shows some errors as above.

Here Is the Ant script I am using.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project basedir="." default="install">
      <taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/deployers/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
          <pathelement location="C:\Program Files\IBM\MobileFirst_Platform_Server\WorklightServer\worklight-ant-deployer.jar"/>
        </classpath>
      </taskdef>

      <target name="databases">
        <configuredatabase kind="Worklight">
          <db2 database="TESTDB" server="172.17.0.177" user="mobusr4" password="mobileuser4">
          </db2>
          <driverclasspath>
            <fileset dir="C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\shared\resources\worklight_1\db2">
              <include name="db2jcc4.jar"/>
              <include name="db2jcc_license_*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
          </driverclasspath>
        </configuredatabase>
        <configuredatabase kind="WorklightReports">
          <db2 database="TESTDB" server="172.17.0.177" user="mobusr4" password="mobileuser4">
                  </db2>
          <driverclasspath>
            <fileset dir="C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\shared\resources\worklight_1\db2">
              <include name="db2jcc4.jar"/>
              <include name="db2jcc_license_*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
          </driverclasspath>
        </configuredatabase>
      </target>

      <target name="install">
        <configureapplicationserver>
          <project warfile="C:\Program Files\agent\var\work\MF-Component\bin\Git_Demo.war" libraryfile="C:\Program Files\IBM\MobileFirst_Platform_Server\WorklightServer\worklight-jee-library.jar"/>

          <!-- Here you can define values which override the 
               default values of Worklight configuration properties -->
          <property name="serverSessionTimeout" value="10"/>    

          <applicationserver>
            <websphereapplicationserver installdir="C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty"
                                        profile="Liberty"
                                        user="admin" password="admin">
              <server name="UCDServer"/>
            </websphereapplicationserver>
          </applicationserver>
          <database kind="Worklight">
            <db2 database="TESTDB" server="172.17.0.177" user="mobusr4" password="mobileuser4"/>
            <driverclasspath>
              <fileset dir="C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\shared\resources\worklight_1\db2">
                <include name="db2jcc4.jar"/>
                <include name="db2jcc_license_*.jar"/>
              </fileset>
            </driverclasspath>
          </database>
          <database kind="WorklightReports">
            <db2 database="TESTDB" server="172.17.0.177" user="mobusr4" password="mobileuser4"/>
            <driverclasspath>
              <fileset dir="C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\shared\resources\worklight_1\db2">
                <include name="db2jcc4.jar"/>
                <include name="db2jcc_license_*.jar"/>
              </fileset>
            </driverclasspath>
          </database>
        </configureapplicationserver>
      </target>
      </project>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is correct, the WAR file needs to have a database. Before creating the datasource in the application server, the configuredatabase Ant task verifies that the datasource exists and has the correct tables. It didn't find it and failed with an error.

To create the database tables run the 'databases' target in your ant file.

For more information, see https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/c_project_war_file_ant_tasks.html